# Word correction library for c++

Tags: c++, cpu-word, ocr

Are there any open-source word correction for c++? I would like to integrate with my c++ program to fix when OCR read some characters wrongly at some positions of the whole word. For example if the OCR output is "Recoqnitl0n" the program will correct it and convert to "Recognition".

Thank you

Comment: @theparitt Just to note, you've asked a few questions and got very few responses. It would help if you improve your style. Take a look at [how others ask](http://stackoverflow.com/faq), and see [whathaveyoutried.com](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are some open source spell checkers. Try:

[hunspell](http://hunspell.sourceforge.net)

or

[aspell](http://aspell.net)